# Rails state_machine not working on staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

```
gem list state*

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
state_machine (1.1.2)
```

In the console on my development environment:

```
>> require 'state_machine'
=> []
```

In my staging environment:

```
>> require 'state_machine'
=> false
```

Both environments have the same state_machine (1.1.2).

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

First, if `require` returns false, it means only that the file has already been successfully loaded.

Are you using bundler to manage gems?  Assuming a Rails 3 app, this is the default, and you should most definitely use it.  If you have a separate environment (using the Rails meaning of "environment") for staging, then be sure your Gemfile.rb lists the `state_machine` gem for all environments.  Finally, in order for changes to the Gemfile.rb to take effect, you must run `bundle install` before it will be available within Rails.